# Problem accessing a form within a script with Jquery and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have problems accessing my form from the JS file, and I don't know how to access it. Here's my code:

```js
$("#my-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var textInput = $("#my-input").val();
  $("#container").html(textInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container-fluid"></div>
<script id="view-contact" type="text/html">
  <form id="my-form" class="form">
    <input id="my-input" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</script>
```

Comment: The form is html it shouldn't be inside the script

Comment: Why is there a `<script>` tag around your form? Remove it, then your code will work.

Comment: If you're using a `<script>` as some for of hack replacement for a [`<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) (or even if you're using an actual template element) then there isn't going to be a submit button to trigger the submit event without some code to create an actual form in the document. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your html inside the *<script>* tag. Put your *JavaScript / JQuery* inside the script tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container-fluid"></div>
<form id="my-form" class="form">
  <input id="my-input" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  $("#my-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var textInput = $("#my-input").val();
    $("#container").html(textInput);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: But can i access the form in any way when it is located in a script? I am trying to make a one-page website..

Comment: then don't put the form inside the script put your jquery / js code inside the script